# Can we change the algorithms used for computing trends when decomposing time series?

Tags: time-series, trend

Classical decomposition consists of the following steps for additive or multiplicative decomposition:

1. Compute trend via a moving average (MA)
2. De-trend the series to get seasonal variation (either by subtraction or division if additive or multiplicative respectively)
3. De-seasonalize the series similarly to get the residuals.

Technically, does it really matter if the in the first step we *change* the algorithm to a weighted MA or a triangular/Gaussian MA or even simple exponential smoothing? The STL/LOWESS decomposition has a different way of computing the trend by local clustering/weighting/regressing. We could then proceed to further decompose in additively or multiplicatively, right? (I currently lack the insight into the decomposition steps of LOESS and am only extrapolating.)

Thus, in theory, we should be able to switch the algorithm for computing the trend and then continue on with either an additive or multiplicative decomposition IMHO (or a mix of both?). Is this commonly practiced? Is there a reason why we can't mix and match the decomposition steps by choosing the *most relevant* ones that best address the situation?

For my purpose, the decomposition graphs are a useful tool for *monitoring* purposes only and was curious if there were any rules being broken if I did something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Yep we can absolutely change the underlying algos and mix-and-match.  For example if you know that the trend process is random noise around the mean with a switchpoint to a new mean then you probably want to use that for your trend rather than a moving average which will be wonky around the switchpoint. The only thing to be real concerned about is your trend model biasing the seasonality piece or vice versa.  That's why certain configurations work way better, for example complex splines before seasonal estimation could smoothen it out **too** much and give you wonky trend.

These ideas are at the core of a dev package I whipped up: Thymeboost. It combines time series decomposition with boosting (thus the name!) but it enables you to mix and match but also apply a learning rate to each individual signal (level/trend, seasonality, exogenous factor). If you use python you can try it out:

```python
pip install ThymeBoost
```

And some examples with some randomly generated time_series but I really need to formalize some documentation:

```python
from ThymeBoost import ThymeBoost as tb
boosted_model = tb.ThymeBoost(trend_estimator = 'linear',
                              split_cost = 'mse',
                              global_cost = 'maicc',
                              fit_type = 'local',
                              seasonal_period = 0,
                              verbose = 1)
output = boosted_model.fit(time_series)
boosted_model.plot_results()
```

[image: ThymeBoost results]

Here 'local' in fit type specifies to look for changepoints, alternatively we can pass 'global' here to just fit on the whole dataset.  And to your point we really can use whatever base estimator for trend so lets use arima:

```python
from ThymeBoost import ThymeBoost as tb
boosted_model = tb.ThymeBoost(trend_estimator = 'ar',
                              arima_order = (2,1,2),
                              split_cost = 'mse',
                              global_cost = 'maicc',
                              fit_type = 'local',
                              seasonal_period = 0,
                              verbose = 1)
output = boosted_model.fit(time_series)
boosted_model.plot_results()
```

[image]

Using verbose the model prints results from each round:

```python
Round 0 cost: -1344.0438903501597
Using Split: 101
Round 1 cost: -1971.2578426717146
Using Split: 151
Round 2 cost: -1953.8696120415427
Boosting Terminated 
Using round 1
```

So it found a changepoint at 101 where the coefficients of the arima will be different. That is close enough to the true changepoint at 100 if you ask me!  Round 0 is always fit with with the median of the data since this approach is heavily influenced by gradient boosting and it has a nice interpretation of saying 'there is no trend'.  Although for your case you may just want to fit all your different models globally for the first round.

Now let's try with 3 changepoints to see what happens:

```python
from ThymeBoost import ThymeBoost as tb
boosted_model = tb.ThymeBoost(trend_estimator = 'linear',
                              split_cost = 'mse',
                              global_cost = 'maicc',
                              fit_type = 'local',
                              seasonal_period = 0,
                              verbose = 1)
output = boosted_model.fit(time_series)
boosted_model.plot_results()
```

[image]

Oof, that's pretty bad.  Looks like it is a problem with how I propose the segments since I don't want to exhaustively try every data point, so let's increase the number of proposals (and you will see I commented out approximate_splits = True if set to False it will try every point):

```python
from ThymeBoost import ThymeBoost as tb
boosted_model = tb.ThymeBoost(trend_estimator = 'linear',
                              split_cost = 'mse',
                              global_cost = 'maicc',
                              fit_type = 'local',
                              seasonal_period = 0,
                              #approximate_splits = True,
                              n_split_proposals = 25,
                              verbose = 1)
output = boosted_model.fit(time_series)
boosted_model.plot_results()
```

[image]

Looks a lot better but it is slow to react to the third changepoint at x = 200.

You can also call plot_components() to see each component.  And finally for seasonality just add seasonality_estimator = 'harmonic' or 'naive' for fourier or simple averaging.  In terms of the seasonal_period you can pass like 12 for monthly data or alternatively [12, 3] for multiple seasonalities. The full list of trend algos is: 'linear', 'mean', 'ewm', 'median', 'ar', 'ses'(simple exp smoothing), 'des' (holt smoothing), and 'loess'. And exogenous_estimator has 'ols' and 'decision_tree'.

There are also options for polynomial expansions and regularization and the learning rate piece I mentioned earlier but I really need to fully document it but hopefully this can give you some ideas and you can try out some of the mix-and-matching and hopefully it doesn't break!

Probably too much of a plug but this question was geared towards my fun little package.

Comment: What a wonderful exposition with your example library. Was genuinely insightful. Yes, adding more documentation would be helpful. For my needs I am not using Python but am open to experimenting. Will give this a shot to tinker with it and see. If I may ask, how do yo compute/deseasonalize the series? Do you "subtract" or "divide" or is it dependent on the trend algorithm. That'll help me close the loop in my understanding of the decomposition process.

Comment: I always subtract (iteratively with boosting) although there is a param called additive which can be True or False.  If it is false then I take the log of my series which turns the whole decomp into multiplicative (while still subtracting in the maths).  I need to add just seasonality being multiplicative which would then be dividing as you describe but it adds some code complexity.  It would be independent of the trend algo and is something you could mix-and-match in something like a grid search to find the best algos/parameters which also comes in the package but it's easy enough to iterate.